# Nested IF's in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two columns with the following possibilities (0 for first column, and then 0 or 1 for second column; or a string for first column, and a 0 or 1 for second column).

```
name,flag
0,0
david,0
0,1
sammy,1
```

How would I create a third column that looks like the following:

```
name+flag
0
david
1
sammy
```

Basically, if there are 2 0's in the two columns in a row, put a 0 in the new column. if there is a string in the first column in the row, no matter what the second column in the row says, put the string in the new column. and if there is a 0 in the first column and a 1 on the second column, put a 1 in the third column.

Can I do this best with nested-if's? I tried something like

```
name, flag, name+flag
0,0,=IF(A2<>0,A2,IF(B2=1,B2,0),0)
```

But it didn't seem to work for me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=IF(A2<>0,A2,IF(B2=1,B2,0),0)
```

Your outer `IF` has 4 arguments, but the inner one has 3. [The documentation](https://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/if-HP005209118.aspx) suggests that 3 is the correct number.

Does this work?

```
=IF(A2<>0,A2,IF(B2=1,B2,0))
```

Comment: Thanks Brendan. I actually just got that same exact answer as you posted. Works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't this work? `=IF(A2=0,B2,A2)`